# Change the font used by \text

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

The `\text` macro can be used to embed text fragments in math formulas. However, if one uses separate math and text fonts (e.g. because the text font does not support math), `\text` of course uses the text font, mixing the two fonts. Is there an easy way to redefine the font used by `\text`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your intentions?

Comment: The text provided by `\text` is to be considered text, thus should be in the text font, not in the math font.

Comment: If you want the roman font used in math then `\mathrm` should do what you want.

Comment: @egreg As an example, consider the following: `\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \forall n > n_0: |a_n - a| < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow a_n \text{ converges to } a$`.

If the math and text font are not the same, it might look better to use the same font for the `\text` as for the math, for consistency. Of course, you might argue that if that is an issue, the fonts do not fit well together. However, even if they do, I would argue that a consistent font would look better.

Comment: @Socob I don't understand. What font should `\text` use instead of the text font? If the font you like for text doesn't have a math font companion, then it's not good for your mathematical document. Can you add to your question some information about your font setup?

Comment: @egreg (I accidentally submitted an incomplete comment the first time – I hope you have seen the edited version.)

I think the font setup I'm trying to do warrants a separate question, as I have other troubles with that. If there is a consensus that it should be possible to mix the text and math font like that without anyone "noticing", I will accept that my intents were misguided. When I asked the question, though, I thought there would be sufficient demand to use the `\mathrm` font for `\text`, as well.

Comment: @Socob Yes, I saw the complete comment. My opinion about what you want to do is that it's wrong: you mustn't have *two* different text fonts in the same paragraph (and in one document, too).

Comment: @egreg Would it be OK to have them in the same paragraph in different documents? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not advisable, as many have commented, but you can redefine the `\text` command to add extra font changing.  For example, it you want slanted text in such situations, you could put the following in your preamble:

```
\let\oldtext\text
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{\oldtext{\normalfont\slshape #1}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldtext\text
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{\oldtext{\normalfont\slshape #1}}

\begin{document}

Ordinary text.
\begin{equation*}
  x = y\quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Less drastic would be to introduce a new command `\mytext`

```
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\text{\normalfont\slshape #1}}
```

which you just use instead of `\text`.